# Is the matrix of exponential kernel with $L^1$ norm positive definite?

Tags: matrices, exponential-function, laplace-transform, covariance, positive-definite

Given an exponential function $f(x) = \exp[-(q_1|x_1|+\dots+q_d|x_d|)]$ 
for $x\in \mathbf{R}^d$ with $q_i > 0 \;(i=1,\dots,d)$.

For any distinct points $y_1,\dots,y_n\in\mathbf{R}^d$,
define the $(i,j)$-entry of matrix $A$ by $A_{i,j}=f(y_i-y_j)$,
is $A$ positive definite ? If so, how to prove this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f$ is the Fourier transform of a positive integrable function. This implies that $f$ is positive definite (i.e., the matrix $(A_{i,j})$ is definite positive for all choices of $y_i$.) This is the easy part of [Bochner's theorem](http://www.math.nus.edu.sg/~matsr/ProbI/Lecture7.pdf).

Comment: Is there an easy way to prove this? Is it easy to compute the inverse Fourier transform?

Comment: There is a proof in the link. The Fourier transform of $e^{-|x|}$ (in $\Bbb R$) is $\dfrac{1}{1+x^2}$.

Comment: I mean an easy way to prove the existence of such a integrable positive measure but you've answered this in your second comment anyway.  Nice link, good answer, +1.